# Game loop not running in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, core-graphics

Im trying to create a game loop in swift 3. I can get the code to run with no errors, but the loop is not running. I've tried moving where I declare the updater but that seems to only result in errors.

**Code:**

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore 

class Circle: UIView {


    @IBOutlet var updater: CADisplayLink!
    var x: CGFloat = 0
    var y: CGFloat = 0
    var b: Board!


    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        UIColor.black.set()
        let updater = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(Circle.gameLoop))
        updater.add(to: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
        updater.preferredFramesPerSecond = 1
        b = Board(frameWidth: self.frame.width)
        b.createGrid().stroke()
    }

    func gameLoop(){
        b.moveDown(x: x, y: y).stroke()
        y = y + 1

    }

}
```

I did not include the code for Board, but I have tested it and it works fine. If you'd like me to add it then leave me a comment and I will. However, I don't think that will be beneficial towards the solution.

Comment: Are you sure the gameLoop is not running? Did you try to log it?

Comment: On further testing I'm fairly sure the loop is running. The problem may be with the `.stroke` in the gameLoop. I think it doesn't know what to draw on. Any ideas how to fix this

Comment: I'm not an expert I this, but it seems really strange that you're creating a `CADisplayLink` in the `draw(_:)` method of a particular view subclass, which you don't store in a property anywhere. Also, you are creating a `Board` there, but don't add it to any superview, so it won't get drawn. I guess you're trying to create a game, but this is a very strange use of UIKit. Have you looked at SpriteKit? It may suit your goals better.